# Cannot parse jsonobject----"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of "

Tags: java, json

```
String json = "{'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String address = jsonObject.getString("address");
    System.out.println("name is:" + name);
    System.out.println("address is:" + address);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("array");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("item " + i + " :" + jsonArray.getString(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Eveything is OK.
But when I put `{'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}` into a file.

```
        File file = new File(fileName);  
        BufferedReader reader = null;           
        try {  
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
            String tempString = null;  
            while ((tempString = reader.readLine()) != null){                   
                JSONObject jo = JSONObject.fromObject(tempString.trim());
                String id = jo.getString("id");
                String name = jo.getString("name");
                log.info(id + ":" + name);
            }  
            reader.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

It tells me `Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of "{'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}`. What's the problem in this code? Can any figure it out for me? Thanks.

my file:

`{'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}`

Comment: don't suppose there's an empty line in the file or something like that?  Maybe you just need to trim the string: JSONObject.fromObject(tempString.trim())

Comment: no empty line there. I did not write the whole error sentence, and i've modified it.trim() does not work.

Comment: Post you file content. How json is written in file.

Comment: Perform a hex dump of the file. Check there isn't a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - e.g. the file might start with the bytes `EF BB BF`. It may not matter in this case but you should use a _Charset_ to [specify an encoding](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsonunicode/wiki/Home/) to your _Reader_.

Comment: where is this `id` parameter in your JSON. You are trying `jo.getString("id")` ?

Comment: @Yagnesh This error has nothing to do with 'A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of "{'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}'

Comment: @McDowell I use `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8");
   reader = new BufferedReader(isr);  
   String tempString = null;  
   while ((tempString = reader.readLine()) != null){  `, and my file starts with `EE BB BF`, i've checked. I learn useful thing from your post. That's great.

Comment: What JSON parser do you use? I also had bad parsers which did not accept empty objects. Does it work if you remove that empty object?

Comment: It's `json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar`.I put other line below to the first line, the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment:

> I use
>
> ```
> InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8");
> reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
> String tempString = null;
> while ((tempString = reader.readLine()) != null){
> ```
>
> , and my file starts with `EE BB BF`, I've checked.

The issue is that the file starts with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The JSON decoder expects the file to begin with a character that can start a JSON type but it's getting U+FEFF.

It would be best if the JSON file did not start with a BOM.

If you must handle this case then you can do it with the buffer:

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(isr);
// remove BOM
buf.mark(1);
if(buf.read() != '\uFEFF') {
  buf.reset();
}
// continue...
```

Comment: buf.mark.error --- `The method mark(int) in the type BufferedReader is not applicable for the arguments ()`. I try buf.mark(0); it works. Thanks you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the string returned in the error, `" {'name': 'Tom','array':[{'a':'111','b':'222','c':'333'},{},{'a':'999'}],'address':'York'}"`, you'll see that in character 1 there is actually a space. What happens if you try removing this space from your file?

Comment: Actually there is no space there. Sorry it's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`.

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "array": [
        {
            "a": "111",
            "b": "222",
            "c": "333"
        },
        {

        },
        {
            "a": "999"
        }
    ],
    "address": "York"
}
```

As defined in the JSON specification http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
>      family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
>      quotation marks.

And `quotation mark` means `"`

Comment: @Ron They are not the same for json. You can test it here http://jsonlint.com/ Test it with single and double quotes. Single quotes will not be valid.